# Deploy workflow in logic app standard through terraform script

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy a workflow into an existing logic app standard through terraform script but couldn’t find anyway.

Comment: What have you tried already? Is there any terraform code? Have there been any errors? Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Basically I cannot find anything which shows how to deploy a workflow in existing logic app standard. There is a separate resource that is azurerm_logic_app_workflow but i want a workflow in existing logic app standard.